# Change image in html keeping size javascript

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I am experimenting an issue while changing an image in a img tag of html.

I did an example in fiddle which works as my webpage with images I found on internet so they are not equal:
http://jsfiddle.net/kZp7V/

This is the script code:

```
    var counterImage = 0;
    var ccI = new Array('http://tiendas.fnac.es/la-canada/files/2010/12/Peque%C3%B1a-orquesta-mediterr%C3%A1neo-300x286.jpg',
                        'http://muack.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/smalldata1.jpg',
                        'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif'
                        );
window.image = function(element){
    if(counterImage < 3){
        document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[counterImage]);
        counterImage++;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[0]);
        counterImage = 1;
    }


}
```

I want that all images to have the same aspect of the first one, I mean, same hight and width.  Is is possible?

I was asked to do it with photoswipe but I find it a little bit difficult so I want to do this now and then, read carefully everything about photoswipe for next week.

EDIT: I changed the class="cropTest" to the div instead of the image and now all images are "resized". I use "" because they are smaller. The img tag adjust to the image but I don't want this happends. I want to have a diferent image but keeping the size. I don't mind the image looks blur or pixelated.

Comment: Does your element with id `EJ_test` have any width attribute set?

Comment: No, I have not created a css for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) to get the current size of the image, and use that information once, for example by checking if the width style has already been set by you. Example:

```
   window.image = function(element){
        if (!document.getElementById("EJ_test").style.width) {
            var currentStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("EJ_test"));
            document.getElementById("EJ_test").style.width = 
                currentStyle.width;
            document.getElementById("EJ_test").style.height = 
                currentStyle.height;
        } 
        if(counterImage < 3){
            document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[counterImage]);
            counterImage++;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("EJ_test").setAttribute('src', ccI[0]);
            counterImage = 1;
        }
    }
```